# Show that a bridge is incident on a maximum degree vertex

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ a graph such that $|V(G)| = p, \Delta(G) = p-1$ and $\delta_G(x) = \Delta(G)$ for some $x \in V(G)$. Show that if $e$ is a bridge of $G$ then $x$ is an endpoint of $e$.

I have so many doubts about if this is provable, because I think that a bridge could be independent of a cut vertex. But anyway, do you have any hints for this?

Comment: I'm guessing $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of the graph, and $\delta_G(x)$ is the degree of $x$? If so, then $\delta_G(x) = |V(G)| - 1$, so $x$ is adjacent to every vertex! That's a strong condition to put on a graph and says a lot about connectivity.

Comment: You're right, but what can we say about connectivity?

Comment: Well, between any two vertices $u$ and $v$ (distinct from each other and $x$), there is a path of length $2$: $(u, x, v)$. If you remove an edge not adjacent to $x$, then you aren't removing the edges $\{u, x\}$ or $\{x, v\}$, so your graph is still connected.

Comment: For future reference, *vertices* is the plural but the singular is *vertex*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well convert to an answer.

If a graph has $n$ vertices and contains a vertex $x$ of degree $n - 1$, then every other vertex is adjacent to $x$. That means, any two vertices are connected by a path of at most length $2$, via the vertex $x$.

If you remove an edge that is not adjacent to $x$, then you still have a graph of $n$ vertices with one vertex of degree $n - 1$, hence it will still be connected. Therefore, removing an edge not adjacent to $x$ cannot disconnect the graph, and hence every bridge must be adjacent to $x$.